# Wildfly error: [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (XNIO-1 I/O-2) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed

Tags: java, jsf, wildfly

Ao tentar executar um projeto pelo Eclipse Mars utilizando o Wildfly 9 no Windows 10 acontece o seguinte erro:

```
11:25:08,167 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (XNIO-1 I/O-2) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host
```

A exibição no console:

```
11:25:05,671 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
11:25:05,914 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
11:25:05,988 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) starting
11:25:07,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
11:25:07,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
11:25:07,094 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=UmariDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
11:25:07,094 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=PostgresDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
11:25:07,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0015: Re-attempting failed deployment Umari.war
11:25:07,121 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found Umari.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Umari.war.dodeploy
11:25:07,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:25:07,157 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
11:25:07,164 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
11:25:07,208 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
11:25:07,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
11:25:07,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
11:25:07,224 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
11:25:07,226 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
11:25:07,226 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:25:07,229 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:25:07,258 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
11:25:07,261 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
11:25:07,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.5.Final)
11:25:07,285 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
11:25:07,303 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
11:25:07,311 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:25:07,404 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:25:07,409 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
11:25:07,419 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
11:25:07,422 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.4)
11:25:07,424 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgres
11:25:07,435 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
11:25:07,436 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
11:25:07,484 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path C:\java_dependencias\wildfly-9.0.2.Final/welcome-content
11:25:07,490 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
11:25:07,496 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
11:25:07,584 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
11:25:07,774 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\java_dependencias\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments
11:25:07,775 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "Umari.war" (runtime-name: "Umari.war")
11:25:07,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/UmariDS]
11:25:07,842 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:25:07,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/PostgresDS]
11:25:08,078 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
11:25:08,167 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (XNIO-1 I/O-2) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host
11:25:09,727 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (XNIO-1 I/O-2) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host
11:25:11,294 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (XNIO-1 I/O-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host
11:25:15,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for UmariPU
11:25:16,321 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Umari.war#UmariPU'
11:25:16,334 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: UmariPU
    ...]
11:25:16,388 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
11:25:16,390 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
11:25:16,391 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
11:25:16,493 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment Umari.war
11:25:16,708 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
11:25:16,767 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named EstabelecimentoBean in deployment unit deployment "Umari.war" are as follows:

    java:global/Umari/EstabelecimentoBean!br.com.umari.ejbs.EstabelecimentoEjb
    java:app/Umari/EstabelecimentoBean!br.com.umari.ejbs.EstabelecimentoEjb
    java:module/EstabelecimentoBean!br.com.umari.ejbs.EstabelecimentoEjb
    java:global/Umari/EstabelecimentoBean
    java:app/Umari/EstabelecimentoBean
    java:module/EstabelecimentoBean

11:25:16,767 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named EstabelecimentoDAOImpl in deployment unit deployment "Umari.war" are as follows:

    java:global/Umari/EstabelecimentoDAOImpl!br.com.umari.dao.EstabelecimentoDAO
    java:app/Umari/EstabelecimentoDAOImpl!br.com.umari.dao.EstabelecimentoDAO
    java:module/EstabelecimentoDAOImpl!br.com.umari.dao.EstabelecimentoDAO
    java:global/Umari/EstabelecimentoDAOImpl
    java:app/Umari/EstabelecimentoDAOImpl
    java:module/EstabelecimentoDAOImpl

11:25:17,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
11:25:17,133 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
11:25:17,134 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: Umari.war
11:25:17,159 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000900: 2.2.16 (SP1)
11:25:17,188 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = Umari.war_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
11:25:17,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = Umari.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
11:25:17,191 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment Umari.war
11:25:17,323 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Umari.war#UmariPU'
11:25:17,382 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
11:25:18,452 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
11:25:18,523 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11:25:19,548 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
11:25:22,870 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
11:25:22,870 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
11:25:22,882 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000396: Updating schema
11:25:22,965 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000262: Table not found: Estabelecimento
11:25:22,971 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000262: Table not found: Estabelecimento
11:25:22,976 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000262: Table not found: Estabelecimento
11:25:25,738 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000232: Schema update complete
11:25:33,859 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2 20150729-1131 para o contexto '/Umari'
11:25:42,937 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Running on PrimeFaces 5.3
11:25:43,015 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /Umari
11:25:43,055 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "Umari.war" (runtime-name : "Umari.war")
11:25:43,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:25:43,509 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:25:43,509 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) started in 38120ms - Started 364 of 536 services (221 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Uma instância do Wildfly já não esta rodando na máquina?

Comment: Não. Mas o wildfly funciona normalmente. Só a aplicação que não.

Comment: Tem firewall ativo? quando instalou o servidor por acaso você colocou ele em arquivos de programas? pode postar o standalone.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dai Victor, blza ?

Vou compartilhar o que passei, veja se te ajuda. Se não fica como dica :-D

Isso acontecia comigo também e comigo foi a seguinte situação. Eu tinhas algumas conexões (java.sql.Connection) que eu pegava do gecenciamento de conexões do servidor {`DataSource`} e gerenciava essas conexões no braço como por exemplo :

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
Context lautx = (Context) context.lookup("java:");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)lautx.lookup("jboss/punit");
connection = ds.getConnection();
```

O que eu nao estava fazendo era fechar as conexões. Por esse motivo o servidor as fechava para mim. Fui atraz dessas conexões e fechei ela no braço:

```
 resultSet.close();
 statement.close();
 connection.close();
```

e nao aconteceu mais esses erros.
Não sei se em seus códigos vc tem casos como o meu, de ter que abrir conexões assim, para mim resolveu. Boa sorte

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma [referencia](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-736). Como workaround, você deve iniciar o JBoss com `-Djboss.remoting.pooled-buffers=false`. Mesmo assim, é interessante ler a issue para entender o que acontece.

Outra [referência](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/231766?tstart=0) diz que é problema relacionado ao Windows.

Comment: Achei o esse poste, mas não entendi muito bem como faz para mudar a porta.
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201728?tstart=0

Comment: Eu até ia te sugerir isso, mas vi que a mensagem era diferente. Para mudar a porta do management, você pode passar via linha de comando ou mudar no standalone. Via linha de comando: `$ ./standalone.sh -Djboss.managment.http.port=8990 -Djboss.managment.https.port=8443 -Djboss.managment.native.port=8999`.